# Installing zip2john tool in Linux

Tags: linux, zip

How do I install the Zip2john tool without installing the John package?

I already has all the John TOOLS except Zip2John. I just want to add it to the package.

I copied the `zip2john.c` code from the [Github repo](https://github.com/openwall/john/blob/bleeding-jumbo/src/zip2john.c) and compiled it. But it has some unmet dependencies.

C compile error:

[image: C compile error]

How do I Install it?

Note: I don't want to Install the whole JohnTheRipper package again.

**The Error:**

```
zip2john.c:121:10: fatal error: arch.h: No such file or directory 
121 | #include "arch.h"
    |
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`zip2john.c` isn’t a standalone file resulting in a standalone utility; it’s a component of (jumbo) JtR as a whole. `john` itself checks how it was invoked, and runs `zip2john` if it was invoked as `zip2john`.

Thus to build `zip2john`, you need to build the full jumbo `john`:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/openwall/john
$ cd john/src
$ ./configure && make
```

If this completes successfully, it will produce a `john` binary in `john/run`, and a `zip2john` symlink to it.

The code is deeply entangled, there’s no simple way of building only `zip2john` and its dependencies.

If you already have a jumbo `john`, you can symlink it without rebuilding anything:

```
ln -s john zip2john
```

Make sure the result works as expected:

```
$ ./zip2john
Usage: ./zip2john [options] [zip file(s)]
 -s Scan archive from the beginning, looking for local file headers. This
    is less reliable than going by the central index, but might work better
    with corrupted or split archives.
Options for 'old' PKZIP encrypted files only:
 -a <filename>   This is a 'known' ASCII file. This can be faster, IF all
    files are larger, and you KNOW that at least one of them starts out as
    'pure' ASCII data.
 -o <filename>   Only use this file from the .zip file.
 -c This will create a 'checksum only' hash.  If there are many encrypted
    files in the .zip file, then this may be an option, and there will be
    enough data that false positives will not be seen.  Up to 8 files are
    supported. These hashes do not reveal actual file data.
 -m Use "file magic" as known-plain if applicable. This can be faster but
    not 100% safe in all situations.

NOTE: By default it is assumed that all files in each archive have the same
password. If that's not the case, the produced hash may be uncrackable.
To avoid this, use -o option to pick a file at a time.
```

If your `john` binary doesn’t support this mode of operation, you’d just get the usual usage output:

```
$ ./zip2john
John the Ripper 1.9.0-jumbo-1+bleeding-c80015001 2022-07-21 20:14:47 +0200 OMP [linux-gnu 64-bit x86_64 AVX2 AC]
Copyright (c) 1996-2022 by Solar Designer and others
Homepage: https://www.openwall.com/john/

Usage: zip2john [OPTIONS] [PASSWORD-FILES]

Use --help to list all available options.
```